# Unity: Missing meshes on all mesh filters on Linux

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, mesh, renderer

I am having some issues while creating the build for the Linux platform. Everything is working perfectly on Windows on the same branch and Unity version(2019.3.13f1 Professional).
Meshes are missing for all mesh filters in the project on Linux machine. They are not even visible in the inspector.

There was an error for no OpenGL support.
Platform StandaloneLinux64 with device OpenGLCore is not supported with High Definition Render Pipeline, no rendering will occur
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:187)
I used Vulkan instead of OpenGL. But the issue persists.

On reloading, an error appears for all meshes:
"Import FBX Errors:
Could not read file abc.FBX. Unexpected file type.

"[Inspector Looks like this on selecting the meshes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDqzn.png)

Comment: A little progress on this issue is that if I download a mesh to the Linux machine first and then drag it into Unity, that mesh becomes visible. But the meshes which are coming directly from version control system, are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The issues was that I had to do "git *lfs* pull" instead of "git pull". This may help any other person.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the OpenGL driver issues, you must also make sure that you do commit the .meta files also in your repository. Internally Unity reference files based on their ids that are located inside these meta files. Without them Unity won't know which external file was assigned to which GameObject and that could also be a cause for not showing the meshes.

However, when you manually drag-and-drop the meshes onto Unity, it recreates the .meta files and assign that to the new GameObject you had just created, which could explain the behaviour you noticed.